# laravel 5.1 check if a session is expired

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.1, php-5.6

I'm working on a laravel 5.1 application and I want to check if a user session has expired after each request, in order to redirect the user to the login page.
in order to do so I have created a middleware that runs on every request, the handle function looks like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
     {
          return redirect()->guest('login');
     }
     return $next($request);
}
```

this does not seem to work correctly, because when I type 'localhost:8000' in google chrome it says 'localhost redirected you too many times', I guess it is because the session have not been started since the user is not logged in, so... is there any better way to do this checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable middleware in certain routes. by adding the login route to the excepted_urls array. For example, add the following at the beginning of the class:

```
 protected $except_urls = [
        'login'
    ];
```

or you can disable it in your web.php/routes.php depending of the version of Laravel you're using by employing route grouping